# svnserve: Unable to restrict access to specific directories

Tags: svn, ssh, ssh-tunnel, svnserve

I have a SVN repository set up which is provided access through svnserve and ssh. 
The command in authorized_keys is set up (only relevant part shown) as:

```
  svnserve -t --tunnel-user="${SSH_CLIENT%% *}" -r "/home/myDir" ...
```

I am trying to use authz to restrict access to different users. 
svn log provides users by IP addresses which is understandable because of the way I have set up tunnel-user. When I try to restrict access to some user as in:

```
      [someRepo:/dir1/dir2]
      192.168.1.55 =
```

It does not work. The full access to the entire repository is granted anyway to this IP.
How do I restrict access to certain folders to some users only?

Is there any way to pass some other Id to be logged in svn, other than IP address to identify user thru svnserve/ssh? I mean how to set tunnel-user to something other than IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Re-read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshauth), pay attention to

> When using svn+ssh:// URLs to access a repository, remember that it's the ssh program prompting for authentication, and not the svn client program.

and

> When running over a tunnel, authorization is primarily controlled by operating system permissions to the repository's database files; it's very much the same as if Harry were accessing the repository directly via a file:// URL.

Thus, short and fast answer will be "No way"